# How does changing track diameter change ball velocity

Tags: experimental-physics, angular-momentum, momentum, projectile

For an experiment;

1. A ball is rolled down a ramp and drops off a table
2. The theoretical and practical horizontal distance of the ball is compared.
3. Adjustments are made to reach the initial distance

I am trying to use marble tracks for this experiment. I noticed that when a balls diameter is almost the same as the tracks diameter, the ball rolls slowly and spins fast. If there is more information on how track diameter affects the velocity of a ball that would be great. Is there a relationship between the two?

Edit: I forgot to mention I was unable to find any information online

Comment: What do you mean by the “tracks diameter”

Comment: could you include the pictures of your setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your setup and question, the following may be an approach.  Assuming the figure below captures the basics of the marble on a track, we can consider the following.

At the top of the ramp, the potential energy is at a maximum and as the marble rolls down the track, the energy gets transferred to a combination of translational kinetic energy and rotational kinetic energy.  Assuming we are measuring the potential energy relative to the bottom of the track, we have the following expression:

$$
E_{0}=\frac{1}{2}mv^{2}+\frac{1}{2}I\omega^{2} \quad \left(1\right)
$$

where $E_{0}$ is the total energy at the top of the track, $m$ is the mass of the marble, $v$ is the linear velocity at the bottom of the track, $I$ is the moment of inertia of the marble, and $\omega$ is the angular velocity of the marble.

As can be seen in the figure below, as the track contacts the marble at wider points the radius $R_{2}$ decreases.  The relationship between the angular velocity and the linear velocity is given by:

$$
v=R_{2}\omega
$$

This expression can be substituted into Eq. (1) to find a relationship between $v$ and $R_{2}$:

$$
E_{0}=\frac{1}{2}mv^{2}+\frac{1}{2}I\frac{v^{2}}{R_{2}^{2}}
$$

$$
E_{0}=\frac{1}{2}v^{2}\left(m+\frac{I}{R_{2}^{2}}\right)
$$

$$
v^{2}=\frac{2E_{0}}{m+\frac{I}{R_{2}^{2}}}
$$

In the above relationship, all the terms are the same for each experiment (assuming the same marble is used and the track diameter is varied), except the $R_{2}$ which depends on the track contact/diameter.  As $R_{2}$ decreases, the velocity $v$ decreases.  In other words, as the track gets wider, the linear velocity decreases (and the angular velocity increases) which you have pointed out in your observations if I understood correctly.

I hope this helps.

[image]